# Gitlab with Auth0 authentication

Tags: gitlab

I'm having problem setting Gitlab with Auth0 authentication. I followed this tutorial https://gitlab.com/help/integration/auth0.md. When I try to sign in with Auth0, I'm redirected back to Gitlab, but there is an error message 'Signing in using your Auth0 account without a pre-existing GitLab account is not allowed.'. I followed this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024270/connect-a-gitlab-account-with-saml but that didn't helped.

When I try to connect existing user with Auth0 the connection is stored, but for some reason the 'Identifier' in the account is empty. I didn't found any option how to configure identifier key or anything similar.

My config looks like this:

```
gitlab_rails['omniauth_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['omniauth_allow_single_sign_on'] = ['oauth2_generic']
gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_link_ldap_user'] = true
gitlab_rails['auto_link_saml_user'] = true
gitlab_rails['omniauth_block_auto_created_users'] = false
gitlab_rails['sync_profile_attributes'] = ['name', 'email', 'location']
gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] = [
  {
    'name' => 'auth0',
    'args' => {
      client_id: 'xxxxx',
      client_secret: 'xxxxx',
      namespace: 'xxx.eu.auth0.com'
    }
  }
]
```

Any idea where can be the problem? GitLab has Standard login, LDAP and now the Auth0 enabled.

There is nothing interesting in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the Auth0 provider to be used.

Set `gitlab_rails['omniauth_allow_single_sign_on'] = ['auth0']` and it should work.

Also, noting the recency of the post, you will also need to add `scope` to your config.

Example:

```
gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] = [
        { "name" => "auth0",
          "args" => { client_id: '...',
                      client_secret: '...',
                      namespace: '....auth0.com',
                      scope: 'openid profile email'
                    }
        }
]
```

Ref: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/38945

Comment: Yes, I found that bug two. It looks like this is the last problem with oauth. I tried to allow single sign on with value 'true', which will allow all omniauth providers.
I'll wait for the bug fix and then update this thread.